# CTE row_number partition row rank using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
insert into #TempUserTable
```

query

```
;with cte as  
(  
select *,row_number() over(partition by (userid) order by login_time) as   'rowrank'  
from #TempUserTable  
)
```

getting error incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: This query snippet is incomplete.   You're creating a CTE, and then not doing a select with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax looks fine, just add your select at the end.

```
;with cte as
(
    select *,row_number() over(partition by (userid) order by login_time) as 'rowrank'
    from #TempUserTable
)
select * 
from cte 
where rowrank = 1
```

Comment: `from #TempUserTable` presumably.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by (userid) order by login_time) as 'rowrank'
from TempUserTable
)
SELECT * 
INTO #tempusertable
FROM cte
```